# Table not displaying for Django when debugging

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have defined models and views and I would like to display a table existing from database. However the script is not displaying any content. Where's the problem? Please take a look into definition of model, views,urls and my home html file trying to display table from database.

**model**

```
from django.db import models

class Patient(models.Model):
    Last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    First_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Contact=models.IntegerField()
    Street=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    House=models.IntegerField()
    City=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Age=models.IntegerField()
    DoB=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Vaccine=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.Last_name
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Patient

def home(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vaccinated/home.html', {'patient': patient,})
```

**home.html**

```html
{% extends 'vaccinated/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
     <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Contact No.</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>House No.</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Vaccine Name</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
            {%  for patient in patients %}
            <tr>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.Last_name}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.First_name}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.Contact}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.Street}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.House}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.City}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.Age}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.DoB}}</a></th>
                <th><a href="{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}" class="nav-link" style="color:black">{{patient.Vaccine}}</a></th>
            </tr>
            {%  endfor %}


    </tbody>
</table>
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls tracker**

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'tracker'

urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**urls vaccination_tracker**

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('tracker.urls')),
]
```

> 

[My Project Panel.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69nan.png)

Debugger is not showing any issues. Pylint only show small suggestions, no errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code in the view from:

```py
    patient = Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vaccinated/home.html', {'patient': patient,})
```

to

```py
    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vaccinated/home.html', {'patients': patients})
```

and then it has to work.
Because you're passing *patient* into the template but iterating over *patients* (s at the end)

Also, you need to add a view and template corresponding to this url `{% url 'tracker:patient' patient.id %}`
At first, I would recommend you to remove all href's from the links inside the *for cycle* in the template for testing it. Then you need to implement detail view with a template for a patient page, after it you will be able to get href's back.

Comment: it gives error saying Reverse for 'patient' not found. 'patient' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: It is another problem. Show your urls.py, please.